# plist error in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, save, plist

I've got this code to save data , it should be working properly but when I run the app when it wants to save the data the it shows me an error this the code is this :(just the part related to plist)

```
class savedata: NSObject {

var finalselectedlist = [String]!()

override init() {
    super.init()
    let plistpath = docpath().stringByAppendingPathComponent("items.plist")
    let filemanager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if filemanager.fileExistsAtPath(plistpath){
        let dataarray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: plistpath)
        finalselectedlist = dataarray as! [String]    // Error is for this line
    }else{
        finalselectedlist = []
    }
}

func docpath() -> NSString {
    let allpaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( .DocumentDirectory , .UserDomainMask, true )
    let docpath = allpaths[0] as NSString

    return docpath

}

func saveItemstoPlist() {
    let plistpath = docpath().stringByAppendingPathComponent("items.plist")
    [finalselectedlist as NSArray].writeToFile(plistpath, atomically: true)

}


}
```

The error is this :

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code =EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
What's the meaning of this error and how can I solve it ??

Comment: Your array isn't castable to an `Array<String>` because it's not an `Array<String>`.

Comment: Verify the content of your `dataarray` before cast it to [String].

Comment: @AMomchilov how can I make it work ???

Comment: @Hoa Please tell me how write the code ??

Comment: FYI I'm Using Xcode 7.2

Comment: What's the content of `dataarray`?

Comment: @AMomchilov as you can see it's a NSArray that contain the conents of Plistpath. Plistpath contains an array which is my finalselectedarray.       What I need is to save an array of string and load it.

Comment: I know it's an `NSArray`, but I don't know what's in that `NSArray`. You're trying to cast it to an `Array<String>`, but clearly that `NSArray` contains items that aren't strings.

Comment: @AMomchilov Actually my app is different from what I'm saying but just as an example I made this simple app with one button one label and one text field and did the coding like below (I sent it as an answer to my post). I am also not sure what to put as finalselectedlist's index to get data

Comment: As I already asked twice before, I cannot answer your question without knowing the content of the plist. Clearly it's not just an array of strings.

Comment: @AMomchilov sorry there was some problem with my browser. I sent the code that send data to my savedata class as an answer to my post. (this and the savedata class is the whole code for my example project

Comment: I'm not sure you're quite getting what i'm saying. I need to know the content of `plist` file at path `plistpath`.

Comment: @AMomchilov This is dataarray : Optional((
        (
    )
))

Comment: and I called this class with this lines for saving     savedata().finalselectedlist.append("something")
                               savedata().saveItemstoPlist()        and for loading is this : 
      
                   var mydata = [String]()
                 mydata = savedata().finalselectedlist

Comment: @AhmadMohammadi What is the content of the `plist` **FILE** at path `plistpath`

Comment: @AMomchilov how can I get the content of plist file ?? the only way I know by NSArray(content of file : plistpath) and it seem it's not correct

Comment: @AhmadMohammadi You can read it into a string (I don't remember how, look it up)

Comment: @AMomchilov   I used this code : print(try? String(contentsOfFile: plistpath)) and I got this :Optional("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">\n<plist version=\"1.0\">\n<array>\n\t<array/>\n</array>\n</plist>\n")

Comment: Is this What you meant ??

Comment: @AhmadMohammadi Yes. As you can see, that's not an array of strings. That's an empty array inside and array. It's not castable to `Array<String>`

Comment: @AMomchilov can tell me how to solve this problem ?? or how can I save and load an array of string another code ??

Comment: @AhmadMohammadi Idk what this file is, where it comes from, or what it represents. I can help you with concrete problems, but I can't help you write your app.